# how do you exclude a type from a log4net log?

Tags: log4net

Specifically I have a chatty assembly provided by a different team which shares the log4net configuration. Usually we send everything to root which has a single file appended.

In this case I want to send the chatty assembly to a separate file. I have achieved this by adding a logger element and second appender. This does log the assembly's messages correctly, but they also appear in root.

I want them excluded from root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding a [LoggerMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter.html) to the root logger, which specifically excludes the new logger you defined for the chatty assembly:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
   <loggerToMatch value="Logger.From.Chatty.Namespace" />
   <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

There are more examples of filters on [this page](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2009/06/log4net-filtering-by-logger.html).

Comment: Perfect. I went through most of the configuration documentation and thought the filters only allowed you to include things, not exclude things. It seemed absurd, so this is perfect.